# Search for key/type of value in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a recursive function that returns an object. The depth of this object varies depending on the input, and the keys are also reliant on input. In JSON format, the object can look something like this:

```
{
    a: {
        b: {
            c: 3 // Keys with an integer value are the target of the search
        },
        c: 2
    }
}
```

How can I find keys either named `c` or containing a value of integer type?

Comment: First: in JavaScript, that's not called an "array".  It's an object.

Comment: You probably can't without some sort of iteration, but you don't have to nest anything, do it recursively.

Comment: @Pointy Updated question with correct terminology.

Comment: @adeneo I specified "without nesting" because several of the other similar questions to this simply gave an answer of nesting because the depth of the object was not variable. I have edited the question removing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function search(obj) {
    for (prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (prop === "c") {
                 console.log(obj[prop]);    // or whatever you want to do here
            } else if (typeof obj[prop] === "object") {
                search(obj[prop]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JVf6D/)

Answer (score 0):

Lodash is great for these:

```
var val = _(obj).map(function recursive(val, key) {
   if (key === 'c')
       return val;
    else if (typeof val === "object") 
       return _.map(val, recursive);
}).flatten().value();
```

Lodash docs: http://lodash.com/docs

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JVf6D/2/